# Does AWS RDS read replication require peering?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, rds, vpc-peering

If you create an RDS instance in one region with a read replica in another (in private VPCs, no public access), is it required to peer the private VPCs for replication to occur or does AWS magically make communication happen in the background?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a peering connection between VPCs to create a cross region read replica.

> You can create a cross-region Read Replica in a VPC from a source DB instance that is not in a VPC. You can also create a cross-region Read Replica that is not in a VPC from a source DB instance that is in a VPC.

References: Official [AWS RDS Replica Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) and my own experience.

Comment: That quote is referring to instances inside & outside a VPC, aka 'EC2 Classic' which is deprecated and not available with recent accounts. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed inter-region VPC peering is *not* required for multi-region read replicas (by actually doing it). Actually it seems inter-region VPC peering was just recently introduced (whereas multi-region read-replica has been around for a while): https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/

I wonder how AWS implements this replication since there is no explicit network path between db instances?